# NDSolveValue and DirchletConditions for cylindrical disk

Tags: differential-equations, graphics3d, finite-element-method

my aim in this is to model the current flow of a cylindrical disk with one end set to potential 0 and the other end set to potential 1. In this section of code I am trying to find  the scalar potential function (so I can then find the electric field). I do not need to know the specific form of the potential function, I just want to make a streamplot of the field (or a 3D vector plot of the field).

Assign the cylindrical disk to R2

```
R2 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.1}, {0, 0, 0.1}}, 1]

(*  sets left circle segment to 0 and right circle segment to 1.  *)

DBC1 = {DirichletCondition[
   u[x, y, z] = 
    0, (-1 <= x <= -0.8 \[And] Abs[y] <= 0.6 \[And] Abs[z] == 0.1)], 
  DirichletCondition[
   u[x, y, z] = 
    1, (0.8 <= x <= 1 \[And] Abs[y] <= 0.6 \[And] Abs[z] == 0.1)]}

Potential = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0,
       DBC2}, u, Element[{x, y, z}, R2]]
```

**ERROR**:

> NDSolveValue::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {True,{DirichletCondition[0,-1<=x<=-0.8&&Abs[y]<=0.6&&Abs[z]==0.1],DirichletCondition[1,0.8<=x<=1&&Abs[y]<=0.6&&Abs[z]==0.1]}}.

I'm not sure how to fix the issue I am facing, any help would be greatly appreciated! Also if anyone knows of an efficient way to get the magnetic field profile that would be great too... Thank you.

Comment: It appears you are mistakenly using `=` where you need `==` in `u[x, y, z] = `, and you also have `DBC1` is one place and `DBC2` in another.  However correcting this only throws others errors.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry that was a mistake in the post. I had corrected these beforehand  but forgot to alter the post accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: The errors @Mr.Wizard pointed out are probably responsible for the message you're seeing. After correcting them and restarting the Kernel, I get the error that a mesh couldn't be generated. I'm guessing this is an issue in version 10.1 that got fixed in version 10.2 (which I haven't installed yet). Are you using version 10.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
R2 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -0.1}, {0, 0, 0.1}}, 1];
DBC1 = {DirichletCondition[
    u[x, y, z] == 
     0, (-1 <= x <= -0.8 \[And] Abs[y] <= 0.6 \[And] Abs[z] == 0.1)], 
   DirichletCondition[
    u[x, y, z] == 
     1, (0.8 <= x <= 1 \[And] Abs[y] <= 0.6 \[And] Abs[z] == 0.1)]};
Potential = 
  NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, DBC1}, u, 
   Element[{x, y, z}, R2]];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ElementMeshSurfacePlot3D[Potential, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

And here a `SliceDensityPlot3D` of the solution inside the object:

```
Show[
 SliceDensityPlot3D[Potential[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] R2, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"]), Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False],
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], R2}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the above solution of user21 you might look at the StreamPlot as follows:

```
    Show[{
  StreamPlot[
    Evaluate[{D[Potential, x], D[Potential, y]} /. z -> 0], {x, -1, 
     1}, {y, -1, 1}] // Quiet,
  RegionPlot[RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], Disk[]], 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[1]]
  }]
```

yielding the following:

[image]

Here the code part

```
RegionPlot[RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], Disk[]], 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[1]]
```

hides the artificial part of the image outside the disk.

Have fun!